# How to return closure from function in Rust language?

Tags: rust, closures, rust-actix

I am pretty new to Rust language and trying to make with Actix web framework. Now I want to return following closure from one function

```
let list = || {
    App::new()
        // enable logger
        .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
        .service(web::resource("/index.html").to(|| async { "Hello world!" }))
        .service(web::resource("/").to(index::home))
        .service(web::resource("/h2").to(index::home2))
};
```

So, I can consume that with

```
HttpServer::new(routes::list())
.bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
.run()
.await
```

So, what will be the signature of Rust function will be?

Comment: I don't see a function in your code. Please edit your question to include a [reprex] to illustrate the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [impl trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html) is for: the closure type itself doesn't have a name, but it allows you to say "function returns some type satisfying these trait bounds" without naming the type. So it should be

```
fn list() -> impl Fn() -> ???
```

Where `???` should be replaced by the return type. See "impl Trait and closures" section in the link for another example.

But note that there still must be a single return type, so you can't e.g. return one of several closures depending on some condition, their types are different!

Comment: I can mark an answer to this, but the problem is this when I do your suggested way like --- fn list() -> impl Fn() -> actix_web::app::App<actix_web::app_service::AppEntry, actix_http::actix_http::Body>. It shows me AppEntry and Body are private members. Any another way to return Actix App ?

Comment: I don't know Actix, but it doesn't seem so: https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/780, https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1005.

Comment: For reference, there is a .configure method on routing table structs that can delegate to a function for setting up (sub)routes.

Doc page https://actix.rs/docs/application/